# Matlab - what kind of file am I dealing with?

Tags: file, matlab

I perform

```
q = load('filepath')

q = 

     groundtruth: [16x16 double]
    observations: [16x16 double]
```

What is q? Is it not a matrix?

This is a binary image, and I expected to see a matrix. In this particular problem, we are dealing with a true image(groundtruth) and a noisy obervation(observations). So I assume the file actually contains 2 binary images, but what is q? What am I getting, and how do I manipulate it?

Answer (score 4):

q is a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1ut1_), containing both your images. To access/manipulate structures you use the notation "*structure.field*". So in your case, if you want to show the groundtruth image, just write

> imshow(q.groundtruth)